# Having a page not found error after submitting a custom form

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a custom html/css form that I have been working with for a bit and I have been able to get the form to render, but when I click the submit button for my form I am hit with an error of:

```
    Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/register
Using the URLconf defined in Sub.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
home/
about/
addinfo/
register/ [name='register']
The current path, register/register, didn’t match any of these.
```

In my views.py file I have it set up to where it should redirect the user back to the homepage like so:

```
return redirect('home/')
```

I have 2 urls.py files, one for the registration app and one for the Main app that renders the home page and other tabs.

Here is my register.urls file:

```
    urlpatterns = [
 path('register/', views.register, name='register')
]
```

Here is my main urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', views.homepage),
    path('about/', views.about),
    path('addinfo/', views.addinfo),
    path('', include('register.urls'))

]
```

**Edit 1** Form action attribute from my form added:

```
<form action="register" method="post" name="Userinfo" id="Userinfo">
```

Comment: Show the form action attribute. I think you are missing trailing `/` in registers it should be `/register/register/`

Comment: Done, hope it helps.

Comment: add trialing slash at the end in form action `register/`

Comment: Did not work somehow

Comment: In registers.url replace the path to this `path('', views.register, name='register')` and then call it how you were calling it.

Comment: all urls must start with '/' so check all of your redirects whether have '/'

Comment: Just checked and it seems like the error came from me including a form action attribute.